# Migrate AsyncStorage from react-native to @react-native-community/async-storage, old saved data lost

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, react-native-ios, asyncstorage

I am migrating `AsyncStorage` in my released project from `"react-native"` to `'@react-native-community/async-storage'` and I have realized that all my previous saved data is lost. Unfortunately I cannot let my retail users lose all their data because of this migration. Is there a way to migrate data saved with `AsyncStorage` from `"react-native"` to `'@react-native-community/async-storage'`? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can check if new storage (from new library) is empty at first time and try to import by using exists/old AsyncStorage library 
to new one:

```
import { AsyncStorage as OldAsyncStorage}  from 'react-native';

importData = () => {
  OldAsyncStorage.getAllKeys.then((keys) => {
    return OldAsyncStorage.multiGet(keys)
      .then((result) => {
        ...
      });
  });
}
```

after that store to new one by using multiSet function.

Comment: is there any solution for it? this answer not working, core async-storage's data is deleted at update installation.

Comment: it gives the error that the AsyncStorage no longer exists in 'react-native'

Answer (score 0):

I have forgot to mention that I was using Expo and now I want to use just ReactNative. I have figured out ReactNative core was using `@"RNCAsyncLocalStorage_V1"` instead of Expo which use `@"RCTAsyncLocalStorage"` so directory path were not matching.

Expo path
https://github.com/expo/expo/blob/15a7ff76abb149962b1c42f617ca97d3f6c98021/ios/Exponent/Versioned/Core/EXVersionManager.m#L348

React Native 
https://github.com/react-native-community/async-storage/commit/8d275ad706c27962f71849119bc0f1be811a375e#diff-54c57f4041d9a698ab027d21344b6e63